# Effects11d.lib file, DirectX11 on visual studio 2017/2015

Tags: c++, directx-11, directx-12

Nowdays my team study DirectX11 with book which name is introduction to 3D game programming with DirectX11.

we are trying to set up our visual studio(ver 2017, 2015) as the book says. But we failed because Effects11d.lib file is missing.

Where can we download or find that file?(the file isn't on C drive where windows installed)

If there is any other solution, please give me an advice

Comment: You are probably looking for [Microsoft/FX11](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DirectX 11 book you are using most likely expects you to be using the legacy DirectX SDK. The issue is that the Windows SDK that comes with VS 2015 and VS 2017 contains *newer* headers than those that shipped in the now 8 years old legacy DirectX SDK where they overlap, and some portion of the legacy DirectX SDK is deprecated so is not present on your system already.

You can still use the legacy DirectX SDK with VS 2015 / VS 2017, but you need to take some extra steps. Most of those steps are detailed at the bottom of this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) page.

> There are also known issues trying to install the legacy DirectX SDK. See [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2011/12/09/known-issue-directx-sdk-june-2010-setup-and-the-s1023-error/).

You should also review the post: [Where’s DXERR.LIB?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/04/24/wheres-dxerr-lib/)

Specifically using the Effects 11 library, you should use the latest from from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11/wiki) which you can also find on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/fx11_desktop_2015/). The latest version works both with and without using the legacy DirectX SDK.

> Ideally you should avoid using the legacy DirectX SDK all together. See [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/) and [The Zombie DirectX SDK](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/03/23/the-zombie-directx-sdk/) for details.